# A#dim7 resolving to Amajor7

Tags: theory

I'm working on a Neo-Soul tune that keeps preceding the Amaj7 (I Chord) with an A# dim7 and some variations. The key is really A Lydian. One time the A# dim7 is replaced by an A9(b5)...and another time it's replaced with an F#7. So...

A# dim7 (chromatic passing/approach/upper-leading?)

A9(5)   (variation of the A# with the D# reinforcing Lydian?)

F#7     (V/ii substituting the V?)

...all leading into the Amaj7 tonic. Any function ideas?

Comment: It would helpful to know what the song is (title and composer or performer).

Comment: So this is your own composition? Notation — or some indication of how long each chord lasts — would help. Harmonic rhythm can have a significant effect on how chromatic chords are interpreted.

Comment: Are all of the chords always in root position? And is the melody always using chord tones? If not, then the melody note could very well change the interpretation of the chord itself.

Comment: No, the chords aren't always in root position. Here's a video of the artist performing this piece. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPYT7ii7wqc&ab_channel=RoyZivMusic
Do you know if you can upload pdfs here? I've transcribed it pretty accurately.

Comment: @Scott You can upload a converted image of the PDF score.

Comment: @Richard...just a regular image format like jpg/png etc.?

Comment: @Scott That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not seeing the overall picture here. The Amaj7 is not a I chord, it is a VI chord. This progression is in C# minor. The heart of this progression is VI-V-i-X where the X is any of the various chords that are used in transition back to the VI. This was not clear to me until you provided the video in comments where the timing and cadence at the end of the first 8 bar phrase could clearly be heard. None of these X chords really have traditional functionality but they do have nice voice leading from the i chord and to the VI chord.

The A#dim7 is actually a Bbm7b5. This is best not thought of as a traditionally functioning chord but rather a chord that just has great voice leading to the Amaj7, 3 common tones and a changing root. If you like you can think of it as a variation of a sub V/VI.

The A9b5 has no A. Rootless chords are a common thing but personally I like to think of this as it’s sub V counterpart, Eb+7. Once again no real functionality unless you want to consider it a V/V delayed by the VI chord in between them.

The F#7 is simply a IV7, a pretty common chord in pop music that often does not resolve. Think “Oye Como Va”. It can be thought of as borrowed from the Dorian mode. It also has several notes in common with the Bbm7b5, which is also why it works well.

If you eliminate the fourth chord of every 2 bar phrase you end up with a very simple VI-V-i progression but the inclusion of these “X” chords add a harmonically rich flavor to the progression. It’s a great thing to understand harmony but don’t get hung up on function, if it sounds good, use it!

Comment: Your analysis makes total sense!! The Amaj7 never felt like "I" to me...I just got lazy with my analysis. Ironically, I analyzed almost every lick in this piece out of C#m7...I should have just gone with my gut! I also considered calling that A9(b5) Eb+7. Ultimately, I viewed the X chord similarly to you; except I was forcing Amaj7 as the "I".

Thank you for the SOLID perspective!

Comment: @Scott My pleasure, glad my answer helped. You can show your appreciation to this and other questions and answers by upvoting and/or accepting them. BTW he only uses the Eb+7 the very first time when he plays by himself, it’s not on the backing track. Too bad, it’s a cool chord!

Answer (score 1):

It is basically this plus adding chord tensions:
/Amaj7-G#7/C#m7-F#7/

Amaj7 = V7/V7 substitute.
G#7 = V7 of Im7 (Dominant)
C#m7 is Im7 (Tonic Minor)
F#7 is IV7 (Subdominant)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

I'm finding it hard to analyse this functionally.   But that's OK.   Chord progressions don't HAVE to be functional in a 'cycle of 5ths' way.

At face value, it's not a very promising sequence.   But we know nothing of the harmonic rhythm or the melody.   If you share notation of the whole thing, or even a recording, possibly it would be clearer.

Comment: Here's a video of the artist performing this piece...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPYT7ii7wqc&ab_channel=RoyZivMusic

I'd upload a pdf of my transcription if I knew how.